# Плеер на сайте

Tags: javascript, плеер, html5

Добрый день, подскажите, есть ли какие-либо полуготовые или готовые решения, чтобы сделать плеер на сайте такого вида:

[image]

Т.е. только Play/Stop и полоса переметки, проигрывания. Чтобы можно было без особых проблем отредактировать под вид, как на скрине.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Готовый пример [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/127295/).